# How to make a generic regex expression to validate UTF-8 special characters in input through JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function myFunction() {
   var str = "W"; 
   var patt1 = /\u0057/g;
   var result = str.match(patt1);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

}
This function will Search for W character as\u0057 is hexadecimal code for W.

If I try to generalize it with 
        var patt1 =/\u00[(\w+)][(\w+)] /g/;
This regex is not working. Why?

Comment: `\uXXXX` is regex syntax representing a single character. It can’t be… subdivided. Are you trying to match `[\u0000-\u00ff]`?

Comment: I would imagine `[\u0020-\u007e]`

Comment: Unicode operator does not support sub-regex.

Comment: Im getting START OF HEADING (U+0001),END OF MEDIUM (U+0019) in my input through text box so i want to avoid these special characters. @Ry yes i want to make a regex which can match special characters which have hexadecimal characters in [\u0000-\u00ff] range. Is there a way to creat a regex which can alert user if he has entered START OF HEADING (U+0001),END OF MEDIUM (U+0019) characters in input box?

Comment: @JaiSamtani: Do you want to check for specific bad characters or only allow specific good characters? To check for (only) those two bad characters, you can use `/[\u0001\u0019]/`.

Comment: Hi @Ry, Please check this link fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm . It has list of all UTF-8 characters, Can you please help me in creating a regex which will allow digits,latin capital letters and latin small letters,brackets,question mark,semicolon,fullstop and will throw an alert if other characters are inserted?

Comment: Hi @Ry, can you help me out with this?

Comment: @JaiSamtani: Why do you only want to allow those? The right regex depends on the reason.

Comment: @Ry the things which i have asked u are the ones i want in input,nobody wants special characters in their inputs. So my primary question is can we make a regex to segregate hexadecimal characters ?

Comment: @JaiSamtani: You specifically asked for what many would consider “special characters” already (accented Latin characters), so I need to know why you want to allow those and not other characters. This is important for reasons like the alternative representation of “é” as “e” plus a combining “´”, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `/[a-z\u00C0-\u017F]/` or `/[a-z\xC0-\xff]/`

https://regex101.com/r/yNG7rf/1

https://regex101.com/r/yNG7rf/2

Comment: That’s a really unusual set of characters to match.

Comment: @Ry:please take a look at this list: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=192&names=-&utf8=0x

Comment: Not sure how that list changes anything.

Comment: Hi @enxaneta, Please check this link https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm . It has list of all UTF-8 characters, Can you please help me in creating a regex which will allow digits,latin capital letters and latin small letters,brackets,question mark,semicolon,fullstop and will throw an alert if other characters are inserted?